# Simple SqlCECommand update won't work. Why?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I can't figure out why this simple update command won't work:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE tbl_Settings set password = '1234')", conn);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Error message:
`There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 42,Token in error = ) ]`

.

My select and insert commands works flawlessly:

```
 SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT password FROM tbl_Settings", conn);
        string password = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have put some wrong closing brace in your query, remove that first.

Write your query like below

```
  SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE tbl_Settings set password = @pwd", conn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd","1234");
```

Comment: Oh my.. Im so blind.. Thank you very much. Funny how blind one can get when looking at the same code too long.
BTW. What use has the Parameters.AddWithValue - thing?
It works just as fine by doing `set password = '1234'` ? Best regards

Comment: Its called preventing Sql Injection. Refer to any links about what is Sql Injection, you will come to know that.

Answer (score 4):

```
"UPDATE tbl_Settings set password = '1234')"
```

Remove the parenthesis

```
"UPDATE tbl_Settings set password = '1234'"
```